# Is Eclipse Bug 471813 related to Aptana?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, egit

I have EGit 4.0 installed on Eclipse Mars (4.5.0). When I try to clone a project from GitHub I always get an error when I get to the "Source Git Repository" dialogue. As soon as I copy in the repository URL, I get the message "Internal error; consult Eclipse error log."

I reported this problem as [bug 471813](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471813). The bug report was promptly closed with this message from Andrey Loskutov:

> Sorry, not Eclipse issue: "Unable to locate secure storage module
>   (com.aptana.ide.security.linux.provider)." Please contact Aptana devs
>   for help.

However, I do not have Aptana installed on this Eclipse instance (nor in any other). Why is this problem being attributed to Aptana?

Comment: Because the error refers to 'com.aptana.ide.security.linux.provider' which seems to be Aptana code, it certainly is not core Eclipse code.

Comment: Why is this code being used/invoked if I never installed Aptana on Eclipse Mars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you had/have aptana installed on another eclipse installation on the same machine. I had the same issue which I resolved by resetting my secure store. Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage -> Contents Tab.

Under the Contents Tab, you will see a list of secure stores on the left. Select the secure store and press the delete button on the right side.

[image]

Comment: Hi Faheem, your answer looks promising, but I can not find any means to reset the secure store in the menu you reference. Could you please detail your answer?

Comment: Edited my answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

This is **VERY LIKELY** an Eclipse problem.  Specifically, eclipse uses the same file to store your git login information for all versions of eclipse installed on your system.  They refer to this as the `Secure Storage` file.

The problem manifests itself when you have a 32 bit and a 64 bit version of eclipse installed.  For me this happened because I use eclipse for python development and Code Composer Studio for embedded software DSP.  Code Composer Studio is a wrapper around a 32 bit version of eclipse.

Because the 32 bit version can't read the 64 bit version of the file you get the error message.

The solution that I use to fix the problem is to launch eclipse with the `-eclipse.keyring` option.

For code composer edit ccstudio.ini.  For Eclipse edit eclipse.ini.  Before the line `-vmargs` add the option:

```
-eclipse.keyring
@user.home/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/secure_storage.32
```

The whole ccstudio.ini file would look something like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
com.ti.ccstudio.branding.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.ti.ccstudio.branding
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-eclipse.keyring
@user.home/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/secure_storage.32
-vmargs
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace_v6_2
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.customizer.class=com.ti.ccstudio.gui.composer.http.jetty.MaqettaJettyCustomizer
-Dccs.minXDCVersion=3.25.5.1
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=30000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=10000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
-XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\ENGINE~1\AppData\Local\TEXASI~1\CCS\ti\2\dmp\\hs_err_%p.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. I encourage you to share this at the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471813).